# How can I generate the OpenAPI arbitrary type using Swagger Core (springdoc-openapi)?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, openapi, springdoc, swagger-core

I am working on an application which uses the [springdoc-openapi](https://springdoc.org) library to generate OpenAPI v3 endpoints for its Spring controllers.  This library uses [Swagger Core](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core) for the actual mapping of Java Objects to OpenAPI schemas.

There is a request/response type used by a controller which includes a property of type `Object`.

```java
public class TypeWithObject {
    private Object value;

    public Object getValue() { return value; }
    public void setValue(Object value) { this.value = value; }
}
```

This type can therefore be any of the [data types](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/) defined by OpenAPI: `string`, `number`, `integer`, `boolean`, `array`, or `object`.  Note that `object` is a distinct type from the other types; e.g. a `string` or `boolean` is not an `object`.

The [OpenAPI 3.0 Specification](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/#any) specifies that a schema without any type will match any data type.

> A schema without a type matches any data type – numbers, strings, objects, and so on.

A proper way to model this, then, would be the following Swagger definition, where there is no `type` property for `value`:

```json
{
  "openapi": "3.0.1",
  "info": {
    "title": "OpenAPI definition",
    "version": "v0"
  },
  "components": {
    "schemas": {
      "TypeWithObject": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "value": {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, per open issue [swagger-core#3834](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/3834), Java `Object` values are mapped to OpenAPI `object` types, not an arbitrary type.  As noted above, this means that it would be incorrect for such an API to return or accept a type that is not an OpenAPI `object`, such as a `string`, `number`, `boolean`, etc.

I made various attempts to get the application to generate this type as the OpenAPI arbitrary type, but to no avail.  One thing I discovered when playing around with using a custom [`ModelConverter`](https://javadoc.io/static/io.swagger.core.v3/swagger-core/2.1.10/io/swagger/v3/core/converter/ModelConverter.html) to use a Swagger [`Schema`](https://javadoc.io/static/io.swagger.core.v3/swagger-models/2.1.10/io/swagger/v3/oas/models/media/Schema.html) with a null `type` is that `Swagger Core` ends up converting the type to `object` as part of its internal processing.  This is currently documented as an open feature request of Swagger Core as [swagger-core#4014](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/4014).

With this all being said: how can I get my generated type to use the OpenAPI arbitrary type?

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to manually define an arbitrary type schema in a separate file, and use the OpenAPI `$ref` keyword (applied using [`@Schema(ref="...")`](https://javadoc.io/static/io.swagger.core.v3/swagger-annotations/2.1.10/io/swagger/v3/oas/annotations/media/Schema.html#ref--)) to reference this type.

**`api-docs-anyvalue.yml`:**

```yaml
components:
  schemas:
    AnyValue: {}
```

```java
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema;

public class TypeWithObject {
    @Schema(ref = "api-docs-anyvalue.yml#/components/schemas/AnyValue")
    private Object value;

    public Object getValue() { return value; }
    public void setValue(Object value) { this.value = value; }
}
```

**Result:**

```json
{
  "openapi": "3.0.1",
  "info": {
    "title": "OpenAPI definition",
    "version": "v0"
  },
  "components": {
    "schemas": {
      "TypeWithObject": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "value": {
            "$ref": "api-docs-anyvalue.yml#/components/schemas/AnyValue"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```